# How to remove the print preview lines in Excel 2010?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Somehow or other I have managed to switch on the print margin lines in Excel 2010. I cannot seem to turn them off. I went to Page Layout->Page Setup->Print Area->Clear Print Area but the lines remain on my screen. Any ideas to get rid of them?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I have Excel 2007 so I'm giving the instructions to hide **page break lines** for Excel 2007, but it should be applicable to Excel 2010 as well:

1. Click on the Office button in the top left corner.
2. Select the *Excel Options* button at the bottom right side of the Office menu.
3. Select *Advanced* in the left column.
4. Scroll down to the *Display Options for this Worksheet* section.
5. Uncheck the box marked *Show Page Breaks*.
6. Click OK.

[image]

Comment: Aha page breaks! I thought it was something to do with printing. Worked a treat, thanks v much.

Comment: +1 for this.  They seem to turn on automatically somehow but I've no idea what I am doing to enable them.  Another question, perhaps :)

Comment: Similar option on the Mac version: `Preferences > View > Show page breaks`

Comment: I've been searching how to get rid of those pesky lines for at least 10min, thank you so much !

Comment: This works in 2010 as well.

Comment: They actually turn on after you have went to print once.

Comment: Why so difficult. I mean, it's so easy to accidentally create them, and it takes 6 steps to get rid of them!?

Comment: Works in Excel 2016 as well.

Comment: Accidentally clicked one button and the lines start showing but there is no easy way to get rid of them. One has to go through all that just to get rid of them. This is completely non-intuitive and crazy. Normally you would expect a toggle on and off using the same button. Christopher Columbus!

Answer (score 18):

You can create a macro and a custom button for your ribbon to toggle them on/off so you don't have to go through the Options every time.

VBA

```
Sub TogglePageBreaks()

  ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = Not ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks

End Sub
```

I created/saved this macro to the Personal.xlsb file (see [Copy your macros to a Personal Macro Workbook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-HA102174076.aspx)).

I then added a button to my Excel 2010 Ribbon for the macro (see [How to add your own Macros to Excel Ribbon](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/02/27/how-to-add-your-own-macros-to-excel-ribbon/)).

Clicking it toggles the page breaks on and off in any spreadsheet you open.

Answer (score 7):

For Excel 2010, go to File, Options, Advanced.  Then page down to `Display options for this worksheet` and uncheck `Show page breaks`.  Be sure you are in `Display options for this worksheet` and not 'this workbook'.  That should do it!!

Comment: My Excel 2010 is not showing an "Office" button (step 1 in Mehper's answer), but *THIS* answer worked.

Comment: Really brilliant answer. But just got 1 up-vote. Hence, I have given the second up-vote

Answer (score 5):

In the Immediate console (Alt + F11 -> Ctro + G), execute the following command: ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaning how to access the Immediate console! Very handy. I see there is no "DisplayPageBreaks" method for `ActiveWorkbook`, how would you disable page break for all workbooks with the same method?

Answer (score 4):

Here are the instructions for Excel 2003:

1. Go to the Tools menu and select Options.
2. Select the View tab.
3. In the Window Options section, uncheck the box marked Page Breaks.
4. Click OK.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way I have found is to simply save your file, close and reopen. The dashed print lines should no longer be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Go to View set "Workbook views" from Page Break preview to Normal. This will remove the background 
Page number" watermark.

Go to Options -> Advanced -> Display options for this worksheet -> Remove "Show page breaks". This will remove the printing dotted lines.

Comment: @fixer1234, you are wrong. This is the only answer that mentions the Workbook Views group on the View tab, which was exactly what I was looking for. If you have downvoted this answer, please remove your downvote.

Comment: @phenry: Fair enough on the first paragraph.  I deleted my comment.  None of the downvotes were mine.  But I'll upvote to offset the remaining downvote on the chance that my comment attracted a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2011 for Mac:

1) Go to Preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)
2) In the `Authoring` section, click `View`
3) On the right under `Window options`, uncheck `Show page breaks`