# How to hide page break lines in Page Layout view in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a work sheet which I need to look at in the **Page Layout View**, however, in that view the page breaks show as dotted lines along the outer border.

I have read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/332412/how-to-remove-the-print-preview-lines-in-excel-2010), and the answer works for the **Normal View**, but not the **Page Layout View**.

Is there a way to hide the page break lines in the page layout view?

Answer (score 0):

I just worked it out a fix for my problem:

On the Page Layout tab, in the Page Setup section, I expanded breaks and "Reset All Page Breaks"

This removed them from the view and let me do what I needed to.